# Add two columns in query using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, having

Hello I have 2 tables and they have 2 columns like this.

```
DocumentNumber       Price
```

And I Showed the same DocumentNumbers in my tables, Count of each document number and The price difference.
Here is my query

```
select DocumentNumber, max(cnt_s) as documentNumber1, max(cnt_s2) as documentNumber1,
       max(price_s) - max(price_s2) as PriceDifference
from ((select DocumentNumber, count(*) as cnt_s, 0 as cnt_s2,
              sum(price) as price_s, 0 as price_s2
       from Sheet s
       group by DocumentNumber
      ) union all
      (select DocumentNumber, 0, count(*) as cnt_s2,
              0, sum(price) as price_s2
       from Sheet2 s2
       group by DocumentNumber
      )
     ) t
group by DocumentNumber;
```

I only want to add price of sheet1 and price of sheet2 before price difference.
Suggest me some queries.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please explain clearly.

Comment: Just  Read query you will be undrestand what is going on and I want only add 2 columns on it price1 and price2

Comment: You wanto to do like this, select DocumentNumber, max(cnt_s) as documentNumber1, max(cnt_s2) as documentNumber1, (max(price_s) - max(price_s2)) as PriceDifference, price_s as price1, price_s2 as price2

Comment: Yeah I do it but it does not work :(

Comment: how t.price_s as price1, t.price_s2 as price2

Comment: I Add "t.price_s as price1, t.price_s2 as price2" but it show me error. I really confused.
"Column 't.price_s' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: maybe you need to have a follow-up question on the user that answered your previous question.

Comment: At least you could've posted a link to the previous question

Comment: His Answer is right But it works Like my Query. I want to show s_price and s2_price and then show the priceDifference.
His Query and my query only shows priceDifference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DocumentNumber, 
       MAX(cnt_s) cnt_s, 
       MAX(cnt_s2) cnt_s2,
       MAX(price_s) price_s,
       MAX(price_s2) price_s2,
       MAX(price_s) - MAX(price_s2) PriceDifference
 FROM 
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s, 
         0          cnt_s2, 
         SUM(price) price_s, 
         0          price_s2
    FROM Sheet
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
  UNION ALL    
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         0          cnt_s, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s2,
         0          price_s, 
         SUM(price) price_s2
    FROM Sheet2
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
) q
 GROUP BY DocumentNumber
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0feb3/11)** demo.

*Note that in your original query you return `max(cnt_s)` and `max(cnt_s2)` under the same alias `documentNumber1` which you shouldn't do*

**UPDATE** As you ask here is a version with `JOIN`

```
SELECT s.DocumentNumber, 
       s.cnt_s, 
       s2.cnt_s2, 
       s.price_s,
       s2.price_s2,
       s.price_s - s2.price_s2 PriceDifference
 FROM 
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s, 
         SUM(price) price_s
    FROM Sheet
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
) s JOIN     
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s2,
         SUM(price) price_s2
    FROM Sheet2
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
) s2 ON s.DocumentNumber = s2.DocumentNumber
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0feb3/15)** demo (with both queries).

*Note that this query assumes that you always have `DocumentNumber` in both `Sheet` and `Sheet2`. Mismatches will be filtered out by `JOIN`. Therefore you might need to use an outer join.*

Comment: Look At my query. I just Want to Show Price_s and Price_s2

Comment: help me do this:
SELECT s.DocumentNumber, 
       s.cnt_s, 
       s2.cnt_s2,
       s.price_s,
       s.price_s2,
       s.price_s - s2.price_s2 PriceDifference
 FROM 
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s, 
         0          cnt_s2, 
         SUM(price) price_s, 
         0          price_s2
    FROM Sheet
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
) s JOIN     
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, 
         0          cnt_s, 
         COUNT(*)   cnt_s2,
         0          price_s, 
         SUM(price) price_s2
    FROM Sheet2
   GROUP BY DocumentNumber
) s2 ON s.DocumentNumber = s2.DocumentNumber

Comment: @MehdiKhalifeh This query ... what?

Comment: This query was the previous query that you showed me. its a bit difference.
I used the query that I mentioned in comment, but it returns price_s2 as zero.
Please complete that query too. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. See updated answer. Maybe that is what you're after. Note that if you were to add to your question a few rows of sample data and desired output based on it we won't be shooting in the dark. Usually it takes only a minute or two (like I did with a sqlfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Hay that can including typo error. If error occur, let me know

```
 SELECT temp.DN, MAX(temp.CNT1) as documentNumber1, MAX(temp.CNT2) as documentNumber1,
 MAX(temp.P1) - MAX(temp.P2) as PriceDifference, temp.P1 as Price1 , 
 temp.P2 as Price2 FROM 
 ((SELECT tbl.DocumentNumber 
 as DNumber,tbl.cnt_s as CNT1,tbl.cnt_s2 as CNT2,
 tbl.price_s as P1,tbl.price_s2 as P2 FROM 
    (select DocNum, count(*) as cnt_s, 0 as cnt_s2,
    SUM(price) as price_s, 0 as price_s2
    FROM Sheet s) 
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT DocNum, 0, count(*) as cnt_s2,
     0, sum(price) as price_s2
     FROM Sheet2 s2
     )
  ) as tbl GROUP BY tbl.DoucmentNumber
 ) temp
group by temp.DN;
```